# Python subclassing - how to update class attribute that is used by another class attribute

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes, subclass, wtforms

Say if there's a class attribute that is calculated depending on another class attribute:

```
class ClassA(object):
    attr1=5
    attr2=attr1+10

>>ClassA.attr2
15
```

And then in a child class I want to update the first class attribute to cause a change in the second one, without re-defining the second. e.g:

```
class ClassB(ClassA):
    attr1=10
```

What I would like to happen is:

```
>>ClassB.attr2
20
```

However this isn't the case since attr2 gets calculated before attr1 is re-defined. Is there a way to obtain this behaviour without redefining the second attribute?

(My particular use case is defining WTForms with Field attributes (format, choices, etc) that are derived from the Form class attributes, so I can subclass a base Form and change these attributes without having to re-define the entire Field.)

Comment: What about making `attr2` a *method*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `@classproperty` descriptor (similar to `@property`) if you don't want to use metaclasses.

Here's a simple implementation of a `classproperty` decorator

```
class classproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = classmethod(fget)

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
```

And some sample usage:

```
class A(object):
    attr1 = 10

    @classproperty
    def attr2(cls):
        return cls.attr1 + 10

class B(A):
    attr1 = 8991
```

And usage of that:

```
>>> A.attr1
10
>>> A.attr2
20
>>> B.attr2
9001
>>> A().attr2
20
>>> B().attr2
9001
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if you write `ClassB.attr2`—as you'd expect to be able to do for a class attribute—you will get the `property` descriptor itself, not 30.

Comment: ah, class attributes, got it -- will adjust with a `@classproperty` implementation

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, using any `@classproperty` requires a metaclass… and once you have a metaclass, just putting a normal `@property` on it already works.

Comment: @abarnert check it out!

Comment: Ah, yeah, that'll work for read-only properties because you can fake it with a non-data descriptor instead of a data descriptor. Good catch.

Comment: This looks like it might be the least intrusive method, I'll see if it works for my case. Another alternative I thought of was defining some Fields in the Forms __init__(), so the correct class attribute b

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this directly.

For instance attributes, rather than class attributes, you can simulate it pretty easily by using [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Either calculate `attr2` on the fly every time you ask for it:

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    @property
    def twoa(self):
        return 2*self.a
```

(possibly adding a cache if calculation is expensive), or recalculate `attr2` whenever anyone modifies `attr1`:

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    @a.setter
    def a(self):
        self._a = a
        self.twoa = 2*a
```

---

That only works because `property` creates a descriptor that you store in the class object, rather than the instance, so when someone looks up `twoa` (in the first example) or `a` (in the second) on a `Spam` instance, it falls back to finding the descriptor on the class.

If you want the first one for a class attribute, it works as-is when looking up values on instances, but not on the class itself (which, unfortunately, is what you're doing in your examples).

And if you need the second one, it won't work at all.

For example:

```
>>> class Spam:
...     a = 10
...     @property
...     def twoa(self):
...         return 2*self.a
>>> spam = Spam()
>>> spam.twoa
20
>>> Spam.twoa
<property at 0x12345678>
>>> class Eggs(Spam):
...     a = 5
>>> eggs = Eggs()
>>> eggs.twoa
10
>>> Eggs.twoa
<property at 0x12345678>
```

If that's not a problem, great. But if it is, you need to put the descriptor on the class's class—that is, a metaclass:

```
class MetaSpam(type):
    @property
    def twoa(cls):
        return 2 * cls.a

class Spam(metaclass=MetaSpam):
    a = 2

class Eggs(Spam):
    a = 3
```

For a simple case like `twoa` (or your `attr2`), dragging in a metaclass is horrible overkill.

But for a case where there's a good chance you're already dragging in custom metaclasses, like a complex forms-and-fields system, it might be appropriate.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I know very little about wtforms, hence keeping it generic in the last paragraph ("But for a case where there's a good chance you're already dragging in custom metaclasses, like a complex forms-and-fields system, it might be appropriate.") If you can update that to make it less vague and wishy-washy, please edit the answer (or to explain it here so I can edit, if you'd prefer).

Comment: can you cache the result from `twoa` in your metaclass example?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I guess I would have to use metaclass approach for my use case

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do those calculations in metaclass' `__new__` method:

```
class MyCalculatedClassAttrsMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        c = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        c.y = c.x + 100
        return c


class A(metaclass=MyCalculatedClassAttrsMeta):
    x = 1


class B(A):
    x = 2


print(A.x, A.y)
print(B.x, B.y)
```

The output will be:

```
1 101
2 202
```